# Drupal checkbox required

Tags: checkbox, drupal, required

I'm using Drupal 6, in the Newsletter box I can get the privacy checkbox to appear, unfortunately it appears after the Submit button, and this is the first problem.

The second problem is that after push Submit, the "required" is not respected.

```html
<?php
// $Id: simplenews-block.tpl.php,v 1.1.2.5 2009/01/02 11:59:33 sutharsan Exp $

/**
 * @file
 * Default theme implementation to display the simplenews block.
 * 
 * Copy this file in your theme directory to create a custom themed block.
 * Rename it to simplenews-block--<tid>.tpl.php to override it for a 
 * newsletter using the newsletter term's id.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - $subscribed: the current user is subscribed to the $tid newsletter
 * - $user: the current user is authenticated
 * - $tid: tid of the newsletter
 * - $message: announcement message (Default: 'Stay informed on our latest news!')
 * - $form: newsletter subscription form *1
 * - $subscription_link: link to subscription form at 'newsletter/subscriptions' *1
 * - $newsletter_link: link to taxonomy list of the newsletter issue *2
 * - $issuelist: list of newsletters (of the $tid newsletter series) *2
 * - $rssfeed: RSS feed of newsletter (series) *2
 * Note 1: requires 'subscribe to newsletters' permission
 * Note 2: requires 'view links in block' or 'administer newsletters' permission
 *
 * Simplenews module controls the display of the block content. The following
 * variables are available for this purpose:
 *  - $use_form       : TRUE = display the form; FALSE = display link to example.com/newsletter/subscriptions
 *  - $use_issue_link : TRUE = display link to newsletter issue list
 *  - $use_issue_list : TRUE = display list of the newsletter issue
 *  - $use_rss        : TRUE = display RSS feed
 *
 * @see template_preprocess_simplenews_block()
 */
?>
  <?php if ($message): ?>
    <p><?php print $message; ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($use_form): ?>
    <?php print $form; ?>

  <label><input type="checkbox" id="privacy" required /></label> <a href="#">Terms and conditions</a>

  <?php elseif ($subscription_link): ?>
    <p><?php print $subscription_link; ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($use_issue_link && $newsletter_link): ?>
    <div class="issues-link"><?php print $newsletter_link; ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($use_issue_list && $issue_list): ?>
    <div class="issues-list"><?php print $issue_list; ?></div>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php if ($use_rss): ?>
    <?php print $rssfeed; ?>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You should probably be altering the form (with a [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6.x)) to insert the checkbox rather than just outputting the checkbox in the template.

Comment: Can you help me to write the correct code?

Comment: I can help correct any mistakes in code you write, but I am not going do it for you.

Comment: I understand what you say, I ask for help because what I can do is what I did and I know it's not enough.

Comment: We do it, thank anyway for the help.